# EF Core - many to many relationship use / access custom join table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to implement a many to many relationship.

The Models -

```cs
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Book> OwnedBooks { get; set; }
}

public class Own
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public User Author { get; set; }
    public List<User> OwnedBy { get; set; } //Not really needed, but without it I can't create the join table "Own"
    [NotMapped]
    public int UsersReached; //Get this via the "Own" table
}
```

The DbContext -

```cs
public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Own> Own { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) => options.UseSqlServer("Server=DESKTOP-BT4H8CA;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=True");

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Book>().HasOne(x => x.Author);

        builder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(x => x.OwnedBooks)
            .WithMany(x => x.OwnedBy)
            .UsingEntity(x => x.ToTable("Own"));

        builder.Entity<Own>()
            .HasKey(x => new {x.BookId, x.UserId});
    }
}
```

I am struggling with accessing the join table "Own". I need it to get the amount of each Book that is sold, without completely loading the users. That's why I don't want to use the auto generated one:

Cannot use table 'Own' for entity type 'BookUser (Dictionary<string, object>)' since it is being used for entity type 'Own' and potentially other entity types, but there is no linking relationship. Add a foreign key to 'BookUser (Dictionary<string, object>)' on the primary key properties and pointing to the primary key on another entity typed mapped to 'Own'.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Not sure why you need access to the join table. I don't see additional properties (columns) there, so just using the navigation properties should be enough. Note that inside Linq to Entities query, navigation properties just serve as metadata for the necessary joins, no entity is loaded if you use let say `user.OwnedBook.Count()` **inside query**.

Comment: If you add collection properties of own entity in book and user entities, it will make CRUD operations a little bit easier for you. Check the following link for more details https://mycodingtips.com/2021/3/16/sample-code-to-create-read-update-and-delete-crud-records-ef-core-many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually use the auto-generated joining table and still get the count of each book sold, *without completely loading the users*.

With your current `User` and `Book` models, configure the relationships as -

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<Book>()
        .HasOne(p => p.Author)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.AuthorId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

    builder.Entity<User>()
        .HasMany(p => p.OwnedBooks)
        .WithMany(p => p.OwnedBy);
}
```

Then you can query the books with their count of sales as -

```cs
var books = dbCtx.Books
        .Select(p => new Book
        {
            Id = p.Id,
            AuthorId = p.AuthorId,
            Author = p.Author,
            UsersReached = p.OwnedBy.Count  // this will not load User entities
        })
        .ToList();
```

**EDIT:**
You can use [`AutoMapper`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) which can do the projection in `.Select()` method for you, like -

```cs
var dtos = _Mapper.ProjectTo<BookDTO>(dbCtx.Books).ToList();
```

For that, you'll need to -

1. create a DTO model with properties you want from the query result, like -

```cs
public class BookDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public int UsersReached { get; set; }
}
```

2. define a map from `Book` to `BookDTO` -

```cs
CreateMap<Book, BookDTO>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Author, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Author.Name))
    .ForMember(d => d.UsersReached, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.OwnedBy.Count));
```

You can remove the `[NotMapped]` property `UsersReached` from the `Book` model.

Comment: Thank you, that works :)
Is there maybe any shorter version to fill the UsersReached Property? Because I have many Queries that would need it, and now I have to "map" the IDs every time

Comment: @Philipp Please check the `EDIT` section.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look into that.
In the meantime I created an extension method for IQueryable<Book> which performs the .Select - 

Would that be considered bad practise?

Comment: @Philipp I would not consider that a bad practice.